# Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.install.InstallMojo java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring, apache, maven

Hello I'm Developing J2EE Application using Maven and Spring ,when i tried to run Maven install command this error appear, and I don't know how to solve it, I searched the web but I got nothing, any help will be appreciated .
thanks.

I'm Using eclipse luna and I'm following Arthur Vin Tutorial.

```js
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building J2EE Application 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ j2eeapplication ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1256 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ j2eeapplication ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ j2eeapplication ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1256 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Java2EEtutorial\WorkSpace\j2eeapplication\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ j2eeapplication ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ j2eeapplication ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ j2eeapplication ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [j2eeapplication] in [C:\Java2EEtutorial\WorkSpace\j2eeapplication\target\j2eeapplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Java2EEtutorial\WorkSpace\j2eeapplication\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [20 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Java2EEtutorial\WorkSpace\j2eeapplication\target\j2eeapplication-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] WEB-INF\web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ j2eeapplication ---
[WARNING] The POM for org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.0.5 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-digest:jar:1.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.apache.maven.plugin.install.InstallMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/codehaus/plexus/digest/DigesterException
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
 at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
 at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:99)
 at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:653)
 at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:863)
 at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:790)
 at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:278)
 at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:210)
 at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:986)
 at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1019)
 at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:982)
 at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1032)
 at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
 at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:86)
 at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:55)
 at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:70)
 at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:100)
 at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.onProvision(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:133)
 at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:109)
 at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:55)
 at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:68)
 at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:47)
 at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:997)
 at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1047)
 at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:993)
 at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:59)
 at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:82)
 at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:260)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:252)
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:462)
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:120)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.codehaus.plexus.digest.DigesterException
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:259)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:235)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:227)
 ... 54 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.527 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-03-22T21:02:50+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/162M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) on project j2eeapplication: Execution default-install of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4:install: org/codehaus/plexus/digest/DigesterException
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.4
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/aghazey/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/aghazey/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/C:/Users/aghazey/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.5/plexus-utils-3.0.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/C:/Users/aghazey/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-digest/1.0/plexus-digest-1.0.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.codehaus.plexus.digest.DigesterException
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

Comment: Try to wipe your whole local Maven repo, looks like some POMs are corrupted.

Comment: @watery I deleted Repo and it works fine Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted Repository and re install command and it works fine with me

Answer (score 1):

If you are on windows, delete folder `codehaus`, you can find it on the following path.

```
C:\Users\MY_CURRENT_USER\.m2\repository\org
```

It works for me.

Comment: No need for the spanish part by the way

Answer (score 0):

Delete only

REPOSITORY_DIRECTORY/org/codehaus/plexus

Answer (score 0):

Try changing JRE by JDK

like this:

[jdk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qn0UJ.png)

It works for me!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).